# What's the risk of keyboard languages being sent via Content-Language header?

Tags: privacy, android, chrome, data-leakage, firefox

The Android versions of Firefox and Chrome/Chromium and all derivatives (Ungoogled Chromium, Bromite, Brave) by default insert *all* the user's configured keyboard input languages into the `Accept-Language` header that is sent with each and every HTTP(S) request.

*Can this be considered a privacy concern, given that one would probably assume that the languages you have configured for the keyboard input are NOT supposed to be communicated to ALL websites that you visit? Is this part of any kind of standard for what browsers must and must not do?*

I regard the keyboard input language configuration as highly personalized and unique to the user, and definitely not something that should be shared with the entire internet.

On a practical level, if you set your keyboard input languages in Android under
**Settings** > **System** > **Languages and Input** > **Gboard** as shown below:

[image: android keyboard input languages]

Now every website you visit gets the following header:

```
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,zh-CN;q=0.8,zh;q=0.7,es-ES;q=0.6,es;q=0.5,pt-BR;q=0.4,pt;q=0.3
```

This alone is enough to identify you as highly unique regardless of you cookies, browsers and any session-specific configs, as can be confirmed by https://amiunique.org/fp

> <sup>This can be mitigated by explicitly removing the extra languages in the browser settings, for example in Chrome, under **Settings** > **Languages** but most users would never even be aware that their browser does this ootb.</sup>

Comment: What's the risk?

Comment: "Can this be considered a privacy concern" -- well, you've tested the situation and it's clear that it's " enough to identify you as highly unique". Haven't you answered your own question?

Comment: It wasn't really an answer but rather a speculation/supposition, so I posted the question in order to understand if it is really valid or just me being too paranoid/suspicious about something that is 'regular best practice'.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind this is likely that whatever languages you support for input you will also be able to understand. Thus this information might be used for giving you the content language you understand, which is a useful feature.

Can this be misused for creating profiles? 
Sure, but there are many more information which can be used for this too.

Is this sufficiently unique by its own?
 Only for very few users, i.e. most users will share the same settings with thousands of others. Because of this it usually not worth to use by its own for general purpose fingerprinting. It is useful though as one of many features inside a fingerprinting and in this case a unique setting will also result in a unique fingerprint.

Could this be done better, without loosing comfort?
It might be sufficient to use the language of the device as primary value in content-language and then add only the 1 or maybe 2 additional languages from the keyboard which are used most. This means less precise fingerprinting but probably does not impact serving of content in the expected language too much.

> I regard the keyboard input language configuration as highly personalized and unique to the user,

Again, I think this is unique only for very few users.

Comment: The unexpected part of this is that browsers pro-actively expose data points that might be used to uniquely identify users even when they enable the "private browsing" mode (which imo is more of a marketing gimmick than anything else). Just using the system locale would have been enough for a generic user.

Comment: @ccpizza: The point of private mode is not about (passive) browser fingerprinting but about active tracking using shared cookies, history, caches ...

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to privacy concern, I often try to imagine what an adversary can do with my data.

- can they be interested in what I consult on merchant sites? Of course they are, for targetted advertising
- are cookies and javascript suitable for that: yes because most sites are not consultable without Javascript and cookies are required at least to have a notion of session because HTTP is a non connected protocol
- can they rely on the language list for that? Most users in one country will have the initial default list of the browser and will never change it. So, it will certainly identify specific users, but IMHO not enough to spend a cent on such a feature

Said differently, it is probably a privacy concern for some users that use a specific language list. Yet I cannot imagine that many adversaries will try to use that - unless if country level adversaries are specifically interested in **your** behaviour. But in that last case, the language list would be a minor concern...

Comment: I don't really see this as a potential vector for individual attacks, but rather as an extra _relevant_ data point (among thousands of others) that state and global actors can use for matching and enriching the profiles of its citizens in an automated way backed with machine learning. And even if the implications might not be obvious or existing today, they might become relevant or weaponizable in the future.